# Is there a maximum size in uploading Excel files with Google API?

Tags: .net, api, google-api, google-drive-api

I built a VB.NET app using Google APIs to upload Excel files to Drive in Google Sheet format. This is the code:

```
 Dim bytearry As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileUpload)
    Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytearry)
    Dim uploadrequest As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = service.Files.Insert(myfile, stream, myfile.Description)
    uploadrequest.Upload()
    Dim File As File = uploadrequest.ResponseBody
```

Code works fine, but when the file size is greater than 12 MB, responseBody is empty and the file is not uploaded

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably, and it might just be 12mb. Not an expert however.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert